# Specifying which README is displayed under a github package connected to a repository

Tags: github, github-package-registry

I built a docker image and published it to github package registry under an organization and linked it to a specific repository. However, I would like to specify a different README file to be displayed in the package registry under the image I published.

Currently, the README that is displayed is the general one for my repository. Is there a way to change/specify which one is displayed for my package?

Comment: No it’s not possible to my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible. When a repository is linked to the package, it will show the repository's readme. When you navigate to a specific version of the package, it will show that version's readme.